# 'Nest.ConnectionSettings' does not contain a definition for 'SetDefaultIndex' and no extension method 'SetDefaultIndex'

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to upgrade ES 1.7.0 to ES 6.3 and for that i updated NEST API 0.12 to 6.1.0 and getting below error -

'Nest.ConnectionSettings' does not contain a definition for 'SetDefaultIndex' and no extension method 'SetDefaultIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'Nest.ConnectionSettings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private void InitializeES()
    {
        _uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchEngineURI"]);
        _indexName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[_connectionStringName];
        _connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(_uri);
        _connectionSettings.SetDefaultIndex(_indexName);
        _connectionSettings.SetTimeout(180000);
        _client = new ElasticClient(_connectionSettings);
        CheckIndexExistance();
    }
```

Please assist

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/index-name-inference.html#_default_index_name_on_connection_settings) doc will help you?

Answer (score 1):

If you update your code to

```
private void InitializeES()
{
    _uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchEngineURI"]);
    _indexName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[_connectionStringName];
    _connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(_uri);
    _connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(_indexName);
    _connectionSettings.RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(180000));
    _client = new ElasticClient(_connectionSettings);
    CheckIndexExistance();
}
```

It'll work. Be sure to read the breaking change notes between

- [1.x to 2.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/breaking-changes.html)
- [2.x to 5.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/_breaking_changes.html)
- [5.x to 6.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/_breaking_changes.html)

As well as blog posts

- https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch
- https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-5-0-released
- https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-elasticsearch-net-6-0-ga